# Tabular one column is not accepting any values

Tags: tables

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=600,center}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}cccccc}
     a1 & a2 & a3 & \neg a3 & g0(a1,a2) & g0(a1,a2) \wedge \neg a3 & g1(a1,a2) & g1(a1,a2) \wedge a3 & (g0(a1,a2)\wedge \neg a3)\vee (g1(a1,a2) \wedge a3)\\
    0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{align*}
```

This is my latex code

My fifth column is not accepting any values it does not show anything

Could someone tell me why? And how to fix that?

Comment: Could you post a complete code? This one is not compilable, and it has nothing to do with `tabularx`, contrary to the tag.

Comment: (i) your table has very strange construction, (ii) it is far to wide that can be fit in `\textwidth`,  (iii) you define nine columns with headers, but the body contain only you have two empty columns. If I rotate table, all table is clear visible. One of possible solution is interchange rows and columns, anothers are rotate column header or use shortens (with `threeparttable`) . For more specific suggestion please extend your code snippet to complete, compilable small document. BTW, use of `aqdjustbox` is not good ida ... (table text become unreadable small).

Answer (score 2):

The main error is using math symbols without entering math mode, but even if you fix it the table will not fit and scaling it will make it unreadable.

I guess you're trying to typeset a truth table, but it's way too wide for any reasonable text width.

You can use labels for the long column headers, explaining them at the bottom of the table.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}w{c}{2.5em}<{$}}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{3}{C}|*{6}{C}}
a_1 &
a_2 & 
a_3 & 
\neg a_3 & 
h_1 &
h_2 &
h_3 &
h_4 &
h_5 \\
\hline
0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&&0&&0&0 \\
\hline\noalign{\vspace{3pt}}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\quad h_1=g_0(a_1,a_2)} \\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\quad h_2=g_0(a_1,a_2) \wedge \neg a_3} \\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\quad h_3=g_1(a_1,a_2)} \\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\quad h_4=g_1(a_1,a_2) \wedge a_3} \\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\quad h_5=(g_0(a_1,a_2)\wedge \neg a_3)\vee (g_1(a_1,a_2) \wedge a_3)} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside the `equation*` environment I make a couple of temporary settings for ease of inputting the table preamble. There are nine columns of fixed width:

```
>{$}w{c}{2.5em}<{$}
```

means “a column with fixed width of 2.5em, with center alignment in the allotted space and contents in math mode”.

Answer (score 1):

You can interchange rows and columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{array}{ll}
    \toprule
a_1                                                         & 0 \\
a_2                                                         & 0 \\
a_3                                                         & 0 \\
    \addlinespace
\neg a_3                                                    & 0 \\    
g_0(a_1,a_2)                                                &   \\
g_0(a_1,a_2) \wedge \neg a_3                                & 0 \\
g_1(a_1,a_2)                                                &   \\
g_1(a_1,a_2)\wedge a_3                                      & 0 \\
(g_0,(a_1,a_2\wedge \neg a_3)\vee (g_1(a_1,a_2)\wedge a_3)  & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
 \end{array}
   \]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not write anything in column 5 so what should be done?
I added some zeros and $$ and this compiles for me:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}ccccc}
    a1 & a2 & a3 & $\neq$ a3 & g0(a1,a2) & g0(a1,a2) $\wedge \neq$ a3 & g1(a1,a2) & g1(a1,a2) $\wedge$ a3 & (g0(a1,a2)$\wedge$ $\neq$ a3) $\vee$ (g1(a1,a2) $\wedge$ a3)\\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0   
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]